# Applying CAGradient mask layer to UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, cagradientlayer

I've got a UITextView, with scrollable text.
I'm trying to apply a gradient layer to it, so the bottom of the visible text is always slightly faded out.

Here's my code:

```
CAGradientLayer *maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

maskLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor], nil];
maskLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8],
                       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
maskLayer.bounds = clueTextView.bounds;
myUITextView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Right now, this is causing the UITextViewLayer to be completely transparant - I see the background color of the UIView that the UITextViewLayer is as subview of.  I can't see any of the text contained within, although I can select and copy the text to paste in to the notes program.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have several problems.

The gradient layer's `colors` property needs to have the same count as its `locations` property.  You are providing 4 locations but only 2 colors.

You are setting the gradient layer's bounds based on `clueTextView` but you are setting it as the mask of `myUITextView`.

You are setting the `bounds` of the gradient layer, but not its `position`.  The default `position` is 0,0, meaning that the center of the gradient layer is at the upper-left corner of `myUITextView`.  It is simpler to just set the `frame` of the gradient layer to the `bounds` of the text view.

If you fix all of these problems, you might get the effect you're looking for.

```
- (void)initTextViewMask {
    CAGradientLayer *maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    maskLayer.colors = @[
        (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
        (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
        (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
    maskLayer.locations = @[ @0.0f, @0.8f, @1.0f ];
    maskLayer.frame = textView_.bounds;
    textView_.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

However, you may discover new problems.

If the user can scroll the text view, you will discover that the gradient moves with the text view, which is probably not what you want.  The easiest way to fix this is to embed the text view inside a container `UIView`, and set the mask on the container view.

If the text view can change size (perhaps due to device rotation), the mask will not automatically change size with it.  You need to update the mask's `frame`, in `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: In my case, I had to embed the `UITextView` inside a `UIView`, because when the `UITextView` had disabled scrolling, then the mask layer didn't work.