# Gradient effect in UITextView iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, gradient

I am working on a project where I need to implement center gradient in UITextView. It must be something like attached image. I cannot use any image at upper of UITextView because I want user interaction in UITextView. Please provide your suggestions. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using nsmutablestring ?

Comment: @IronManGill This should be the UITtextview where user can change the text and scroll it up and down. Should I be able to do same with NSMutableString?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845590/applying-cagradient-mask-layer-to-uitextview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If you apply CAGRradient Layer on UITextView and set [txtView.layer setMask:gradient] this will create problem while scrolling means the gradient layer will scroll.
>   To overcome from this problem you must use a UiView working as a container view for your textView. first of all add your container view and then add your text view as subview in your container view. and then use this code which save my life.

```
 CAGradientLayer  gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = view_bottomMenu.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[[UIColor blackColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2] CGColor],(id)[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3] CGColor],(id)[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3] CGColor],(id)[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3] CGColor],  (id)[[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0] CGColor], (id)[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3] CGColor],(id)[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3] CGColor],(id)[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3] CGColor],
                       (id)[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2] CGColor], nil];

    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f,0.0f);
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 1.0f);

    [view_bottomMenu.layer setMask:gradient];
```

> where view_bottomMenu is UIView working as container view.here is my output.
>   [image]

Answer (score 0):

For achieving this kind of effect you would have to implement **masking** on the `UItextView` . Please check

[Applying CAGradient mask layer to UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845590/applying-cagradient-mask-layer-to-uitextview) .

This shows how to change the color and fade certain parts of the `UITextView`.