# How give gradient on text in TextView iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I would like to give gradient effect on text in UITextView, when I try using gradient layer its applied on complete textview background. I just want it tp be applied on text and background coloraturas should separate.

I want output like this :

[image]

And its coming like this:

[image]

Can someone suggest how to achieve output like first image on UITextView

**I am specifically looking solution for UITextView, instead UILabel or UIView**

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: https://medium.com/@kgellci/quickly-apply-gradient-colors-to-text-in-ios-299f7639b514

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradient effect in UITextView iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355106/gradient-effect-in-uitextview-iphone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a patterned color for your text. So, you can apply this color to any text component(like a label,textView, button, etc).

Please check the below example. where you can customize your color pattern in the getGradientLayer() method.

```
func gradientColor(bounds: CGRect, gradientLayer :CAGradientLayer) -> UIColor? {
//We are creating UIImage to get gradient color.
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
      gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
      let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      return UIColor(patternImage: image!)
}
func getGradientLayer(bounds : CGRect) -> CAGradientLayer{
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    return gradient
}

let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
textView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize:50)
textView.textAlignment = .center
textView.text = "Hello World!"
let gradient = getGradientLayer(bounds: textView.bounds)
textView.textColor = gradientColor(bounds: textView.bounds, gradientLayer: gradient)
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Manikandan yes its working for me, I am very happy with the solution

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to achieve this is to create a UIView with the desired gradient, over your UILabel or UITextView and then mask the gradient UIView over the textView.

There is a good tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@kgellci/quickly-apply-gradient-colors-to-text-in-ios-299f7639b514).

Comment: I am able to give on UILabel, but component used in app is UITextView so I am looking for solution for text view

Comment: This also works for UITextView of course @TarunSeera