# UITextView - addSubview - Autolayout

Tags: ios, uitextview, autolayout

**Problem:**

- I have created a subclass of `UITextView` and added a subview v1.
- I am using Autolayout, so I tried to add constraints for positioning the subview v1.

**Error:**

It throws the following error:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews.`

**Attempts Made:**

- I have tried creating the constraints inside `layoutSubviews` and yet i get the same error

**Objective**

- My main objective is to add a fading effect at the bottom of the text view

**Question:**

1. Is there a better way to attain my objective ?
2. How do I resolve this error ?

Comment: See possible better approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845590/applying-cagradient-mask-layer-to-uitextview

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion led to the final solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @mackworth for the suggestion which led to the solution

For completeness I am answering it.

**Overview:**

There seems to be some trouble adding subview on `UITextView` and then using Autolayout.

**Solution:**

So the solution is to create the HazeView as a subview to the parent view of `UITextView`.

**Steps:**

1. Create a `UITextView`
2. Create a HazeView (subclass from UIView)
3. Add both `UITextView` and `HazeView` as subview to the same parent view
4. Position `HazeView` at the bottom of the `UITextView`
5. Ensure that the background colour of HazeView is `[UIColor clearColor]`
6. Disable user interaction on `HazeView`
7. It is best to create a subclass of `UIView` and put the `UITextView` and `HazeView` inside that so that it can be reusable

**Creating HazeView:**

```
self.hazeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

`HazeView` is a subclass of `UIView`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor *color1 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0
                                   blue:1.0 alpha:0.25];

    UIColor *color2 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0
                                   blue:1.0 alpha:0.5];

    UIColor *color3 = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0
                                   blue:1.0 alpha:0.75];

    NSArray *gradientColors = @[(id) color1.CGColor,
                                (id) color2.CGColor,
                                (id) color3.CGColor];

    CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0, 0.50, 1};
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) gradientColors, gradientLocations);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use the following library for Autolayout:

https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

It is very easy to add constraints with this.

Create the subclass of `UITextView` and add the constraints in `-(void)didMoveToSuperview`
as:

```
-(void)didMoveToSuperview
{
    [self.subview pinToSuperviewEdges:JRTViewPinBottomEdge | JRTViewPinLeftEdge | JRTViewPinRightEdge inset:0];
    [self.subview constrainToHeight:10];
}
```